# No access to cooresponding .cs file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The `aspx` page that I need to add code to has an `aspx.cs` file which was written by a company that has this `aspx.cs` file on their system (per contract) and I cannot modify/access. 
Example:   MyFile.aspx   and no access file MyFile.aspx.cs

I need to use a label.text from the page in the control pages and also depending on `IF ELSEIF` statements it will call which of the different controls that it needs to execute.

What is a good way to do this when one does not have access to the `aspx.cs` file?

I have spent a couple days trying to find/figure out answers to this problem and keep running into problems.

Comment: As mentioned by jods, this is likely more of a legal problem than a technical one. Do make sure to get explicit acceptance from your client on the chosen solution so your behind is not the one getting kicked if the vendor sues your client :-)

Answer (score 4):

You do have a strange situation here ;)

Here's one wild idea. You can change the `Inherits` attribute at the top of the `.aspx` file to substitue your own class instead.

Of course that means you have to rewrite all the logic behind the page -- or you can try to have your own class inherit the original one, but depending on visibility of original code this may not work.

Another option could be to use a decompiler to re-create all the source code of the web project from the compiled dll. But you may not be legally allowed to do that -- although I would point out that if you don't have the rights to use the code, you probably don't have the rights to use the `.aspx` either, even if you have access to them.

Comment: Legally don't think I would be able to use a decomplier and re-create all the source code.  How the contract is makes it so certain code the company I am writing for and myself have the ability to access, modify and add to only the files that are on the webserver.  There are files such as the .cs file that I want to add to that we do not.  That being said, I guess I could ask this other company if they can add code to the file, however, it means that I can't do update as I go with adding information, unless I come up with a control page that will direct to the other control pages.

Comment: As for changing the Inherits to substitute my own class, I am not sure what it will break on the current page.

Comment: Note that if you can't repackage the site dll that sits on the web server, I am not sure how you will be able to change any behavior at all... If you write a new class for the code behind the page, how will it get loaded and found? You would need to dynamically inject your dll into the process... tricky. Maybe with a `<script runat=server>` block.

Comment: I have been able to create usercontrol pages which I will add to the page I need it on by using a placeholder control.  Now I am just working on getting it to work correctly.

Comment: Quick note:  I contacted the company that created some of the pages and dll files and was able to obtain the information for use of the encrypted database login.  They have been great with working with me on this. So, there are no legal issues that we are having to worry about.